# IOTA Seed less then 81 characters

Tags: seed

i bought some iota late 2017 but the seed i created at the time on the desktop wallet was less then 81 characters and it worked fine, i thought id wait until the official wallet came out and would then move, so i downloaded new wallet on my phone, now id like to transfer those iota out of the old seed and into a new one, but there appears to be a validation in place where seed can't be shorted then 81 characters? some help please

Answer (score 3):

As seen in the following line, the old app would append 9s to the seed you entered until it reached 81 characters.
If you do this manually, it should contain the same balance and will work on the new trinity wallet.

https://github.com/iotaledger/wallet/blob/445ae8e30de77de33e12c7796e03fd84daea32d3/ui/js/ui.login.js#L110

Comment: It's not working for me. I still have a 0i balance on the account, even with the 9s after (or before)

Comment: Have a look at this page here:
https://github.com/iota-community/IOTA-Discord/blob/main/help/iota-recovery-tips.md